# react-router v3.2.4 redirect issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

after quite a few hours of googling, my solutions for mutating location.state using available route params all failed, so turned here with this use case please:

I'm restricted to use:

```
"react-router": "^3.2.4", "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
```

My component on route "/a/b/" has location.state.somevar and I need to mutate this "somevar" in case the route has a params such as "/a/b/:c", so that somevar=c

My solution was to have 2 routes, one will read params from props and if /:c is available, the Route will contain:

```
<Redirect to={pathname: '/a/b', state: {somevar: 'c'}/>
```

But in this case I get error:

```
<Redirect> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered
```

All attempts to use withRouter, etc. failed.

Please suggest a solution.

### **Edit:**

This is just with the hope that it'd be helpful for someone in similar case:
Any way I tried to use Redirect component with router v3 all failed!
Eventually, I made a component inside the Route component itself like:

```
<Route path="/somewhere" component={()=>{ // detail }
```

and returned a spinner, while waiting for data from api call, via useContext like:

```
const expectedData = useContext(SomeContext)
```

and conditionally returning either that spinner I said, or in case expectedData is available then:

```
// inside component:
const { router } = props
if(expectedData){
  router.push({pathname: '/newPath/', state: {some:'thing'})
  return null //important! you must return something as a React function
}
return <Spinner />
```

and that's it. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, I think, is that you're not passing in a proper object to `<Redirect />`

```
<Redirect to={pathname: '/a/b', state: {somevar: 'c'}/>
```

Should be:

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/a/b', state: {somevar: 'c'} }}/>

// which is
<Redirect to={{
  pathname: '/a/b', 
  state: { somevar: 'c' }
}}/>
```

I broke it out so that you can see the object, you need the `{}` inside `{}` to show that it is an object.

Comment: Thank you, this is not the issue, as in the text of my question I have that typos but in code I have it correctly as you wrote a proper object (I copy/pasted from documentation). The issue persists.

Comment: @Newjavascripter no worries, I definitely recommend having as close to the correct code as you can in the question, as a lot of the time these issues are simple typos and we can help to spot them. It's harder if that's not the code though

Comment: and sorry I couldn't vote you up for I still don't have enough reputation :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, you should use single route to handle this issue.

Your route:

```
<Route path="/a/b/:someVar" component={YourComponent}>
```

Your Component:

```
const { someVar } = this.props.match.params
// is will replace your url without reload or redirect
this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/a/b'})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not change props.location.state.someVar, which is my requirement :(

Comment: I didn't vote up for you just because of not having enough votes still to let me do that. Sorry! :-)